# Can I make my own malt?

Tags: bread, malt

The malt that I found in the store is barley malt.

I have a bread recipe that calls for rye malt.

I have whole rye grain. What do I have to do to make rye malt? Would it be the same with any malted grain?

** edit **
Related to this answer:
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21691/2001

I have sprouted and then dried wheat to use as a sweetener in bread. What process should I use to produce diastatic malt at home? What temperatures should be used?

Comment: For a very rough info on malting, see http://drinks.seriouseats.com/2012/02/what-is-single-malt-scotch-whisky-speyside-lowlands-highlands-islay-cocktail-101.html

Comment: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4480/how-do-you-malt-your-own-barley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not, it's the same process

Many commercial brewers make a barley and rye malt for beer (< 10% rye). A good brewers supply shop should have rye malt too

Rye is around ~40% carbohydrate, while barley is ~45% carbohydrate, so rye is not as sweet, but has a more interesting taste (IMHO)

The differences for making malt rye over malt barley, assuming you have hulled rye:

- Rye absorbs water faster, so steep for less time (~30% less)
- Do not let it go mushy or it will not germinate
- Rye is more fragile with no hull and a thin "skin". So must be handled more carefully once steeped. If it is damaged it wont germinate
- Lower germination rate (due to above), so less conversion, so less sugars and flavour

Otherwise just follow the normal malt barley process, which is well documented